# Python instantiating a function class in another function

Tags: python, function, class, object

I am trying to solve the following challenge. printName function has to get the name which has been instantiated in the readName function. I am at totally without a clue. I want to know the code to enter in the printName function to make the below code work

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name

# Your solution in below function
def printName(name: Person):
    result = None
    '''
    your code here
    '''
    return result


# No Change below this
def readName(array):
    name = Person(array[0], array[1])
    return name


    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = readName(['Python', 'Newbie'])
    print(printName(name))
```

Comment: `result = [name.first_name, name.last_name]`

Comment: You have to return some value from your readName function - add `return name`, otherwise it will return None.

Comment: name is only local to readName, return it and then use @trincot's comment

Comment: Guys, note that place marked with "your code here" ... the `return` is below it. It should not be touched.

Comment: The part below "No change below this" has a problem (see above comments). Are you really sure it is like that?? If so, this challenge material is bad, and you better look for quality elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Person:
  def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name

# Your solution in below function
def printName(name: Person):
    return [name.first_name, name.last_name]


# No Change below this
def readName([first_name, last_name]):
    return Person(first_name, last_name)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = readName([Python, Newbie])
    print(printName(name))
```

Please also consider reading, https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/